# subprocess.call() of 'sort' command within Django script is adding \M to the end of my files

Tags: python, django, linux, unix, sorting

I am messing around with Django.  I have a custom admin script in one of my apps (inside the management/commands folder) that has a subprocess.call() line.  I am doing a 'sort A.csv -o A_sorted.csv' call.  The sorted file that gets written is full of '^M' at the end of every line.  I find this doesn't happen when running the sort command from the command line or calling the same command through subprocess.call() from within a normal python script not running in Django.

Any ideas on why this is happening and what I can do to keep this from happening?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is highly unlikely that `sort` would on its own volition change line endings from Unix to Windows. It is more likely that `A.csv` already contains Windows line endings, and `sort` merely preserves them. If it is your script that's creating `A.csv` in the first place, double-check the newline convention that's being used.

Comment: The file A.csv does not contain windows style line endings before I run this script.  I believe I have fixed the problem.  I hadn't closed the files the csv writer was using before I sorted them.  I added some close statements and ran the script and the line ending characters were gone.